# What is the square root of a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the $\sqrt{x^2}$? Is it just $x$ or $\pm x$? When is it $\pm x$? So if I had $\sqrt {\sin^2(x)}$ is it then $\sin(x)$?

I feel like its just $x$ as $x^2$ is always positive. Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: $|x|{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: "its just $x$ as $x^2$ is always positive": but what if $x<0$ ?

Comment: It can be both. But for some positive number problems ( not always diophantine) we only take positive. Like finding the side of a square given the area.

Comment: So @YvesDaoust it is $\pm x$?

Comment: There are two definitions. If you take the square root as "a number that has the given square", than obviously $x^2=(-x)^2$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$. The other definition states that the (main branch of the) square root is a positive function, then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. (Notice that $|x|=\pm x$, *depending on the sign of* $x$.)

Comment: Ok, but if I was trying to solve for $x$ I'd need to take it as the $\pm x$?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times on this site. See [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778970/why-is-the-square-root-of-a-number-not-plus-or-minus/1779001#1779001) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example can be interesting here. Take $x=-3$. Then $$\sqrt{(-3)^2} = \sqrt{9} =3$$ because a square root of something must be positive by definition. Hence you see that the answer is not $x=-3$ but $3$ which is equal to $-x$. You can do the same with every negative number and will see that $$\sqrt{x^2}=-x$$ if $x$ is negative. Of course $$\sqrt{x^2}=x$$ if $x$ is positive. In conclusion $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$